# Rails skip initializer on asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to skip one of my initializer files during asset precompilation. Is this possible in Rails 4? Seems like `initialize_on_precompile` was removed.

thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? been looking for like 2 hours now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do this in a rails way. We have done something like below

```
if ENV['ASSET_PRECOMPILE'].blank?
  Airbrake.configure do |config|
    config.project_id = ENV['AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID']
    config.project_key = ENV['AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_KEY']
    config.ignore_environments = %w(test development)
    config.environment = Rails.env
  end
end
```

and when running the asset:precompile task

```
ASSET_PRECOMPILE=1 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```